# AttributeError: 'Quantity' object has no 'simplified' member

Tags: python, python-3.x

Escribí en una función la ley de Planck y cuando voy a comprobar si funciona me da este error. ¿Alguien me puede decir por qué me sale este error?

[image]

```py
"""                                     

    def Planck(lamb, T)
    """
        I = 2 * np.pi*ct.h * (ct.c)**2 / lamb**5 *  \
            1 / (np.e((ct.h*ct.c 
            / (lamb*ct.k_B*T)).simplified)-1)
        return I.rescale(pq.watt/(pq.m**2 * pq.nm *pq.sr))
    
    Planck( 5000 *unit.nm, 5780 *unit.K)
 
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-66-35c519268694> in <module>
    ----> 1 Planck( 5000 *unit.nm, 5780 *unit.K)
    
    <ipython-input-63-547d9a8a5b6d> in Planck(lamb, T)
          1 def Planck(lamb, T):
          2     I = 2 * np.pi*ct.h * (ct.c)**2 / lamb**5 *  \
    ----> 3         1 / (np.e((ct.h*ct.c 
          4         / (lamb*ct.k_B*T)).simplified)-1)
          5     return I.rescale(pq.watt/(pq.m**2 * pq.nm *pq.sr))
    
    ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\astropy\units\quantity.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
        839         """
        840         if not self._include_easy_conversion_members:
    --> 841             raise AttributeError(
        842                 "'{}' object has no '{}' member".format(
        843                     self.__class__.__name__,
    
    AttributeError: 'Quantity' object has no 'simplified' member
```

Comment: Mira, si quieres ayuda tienes que publicar el código tal que sea llegar-y-copiar. Revisa [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Agrega el código completo y en texto. El error no nos ayuda más que para saber el tipo de error.